# Set a Boolean value to false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a callback on my model so that if a boolean value is set to true, the callback would set it to false, like below:

```
after_create :set_boolean

def set_boolean
  if self.status == true
    self.name = "XYZ"
    self.status = !self.status
    self.save
  end
end
```

Using the above callback I am able to update the value of `name` to `XYZ` but the value of the status variable is still set to true. I guess, the callback is obviously working but unable to figure out where the problem is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use `before_create` so that you don't have to save your model twice?

Comment: I am using after_create as I need to use the `id` field to do some action. I need to update the `status` to `false` after the action is completed.

Answer (score 1):

after creating , you may specify a function in `model` that'll set the attribute value to `false` like below

**In Model**

```
after_create :set_status

def set_status
  self.status = false
end
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to wrap the assignment into a parenthesis before the `!` operator.

```
self.status = !(self.status)
```

Comment: No, it does not work. Even I tried to set `self.staus = false` but still not working.

Comment: can you change it to `save!`and tell me if it raises an error? Given that you use the `!(self.status)`